# Relation Proofs on finite set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this problem I can't figure out how to do it
Suppose A and B are finite sets and $f : A → B$ is surjective. Is it true that the relation $“|A| < |B|”$ is a sufficient condition for claming that $f$ is a bijection?

Comment: Surely, you mean $|A| \le |B|$, and yes. Think about what would happen if the preimage of some $b \in B$ was to contain two values.

Comment: Hm. For the case of finite sets $f: A \to B$ surjective means $|A| \ge |B|$, as $A \supseteq \bigcup f^{-1}(\{b\})$ (where the $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ are obviously disjoint and have cardinality greater 1). $|A| < |B|$ cannot happen or if it happens you can conclude anything via the contradiction you assume.

Answer (score 0):

If $|A|=|B|$ not necessarily. For example consider the map from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb N$ given by $n\mapsto |n|$. It is surjective but not a bijection.

However when $A$ and $B$ have finite cardinalities and $|A|=|B|=n$ it is true that $f$ must be injective. Why? suppose two elements map to the same thing, then the range of $f$ has cardinality at most $n-1$.

On the other hand if $|A|<|B|$ you can't have a surjective map from $A$ to $B$. So i guess by vacuity it could be true.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are finite